# What are the "paused" values in GC_CONCURRENT log messages?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to explore the behavior of the new concurrent garbage collector in GingerBread (2.3).

Could someone please explain these example log lines in details (especially the "paused" parts of `GC_CONCURRENT` and `GC_FOR_MALLOC`)?

```
12-24 10:20:54.912 D/dalvikvm(  414): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 57% free 2529K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 8ms+5ms

12-24 10:20:54.963 D/dalvikvm(  414): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 510K, 57% free 2529K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 47ms
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `GC_CONCURRENT` Heap is (almost) full. Therefore concurrent GC kicks in
- `freed 510K`  - Amount of memory freed
- `57% free` - Memory after freeing %
- `2529K/5831K`  - Actual mem in heap
- `external 716K/1038K` - Externally allocated memory (memory that is not in dvm)
- `paused 8ms+5ms` - time taken for GC

> especially the "paused" parts

For concurrent collections there are two pause times. One is at the beginning of the collection and other towards the end. For non-concurrent collection there will be only one pause time.

Answer (score 5):

if you haven't yet, check out this video:
http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html